# Google says: Sitemap.xml is HTML

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I created a sitemap (which is generated dynamically) and routed to it using reverse-proxy in Nginx.  I uploaded the URL to the Google search console.
I got an error right away as seen in the picture. "Sitemap is HTML"

[image: screenshot of Google Search Console with the Message "Sitemap is HTML"]

After digging around a while it appeared our pre-renderer had picked up the request and served to google a pre-rendered version of the XML file, thus in Html.
But even after fixing this, making sure no request for sitemap.xml goes to our pre-renderer google still, gives the same error message.

I have tried removing it and adding it again in the search console multiple times on different days, I have tried waiting, I have tried serving it with another name (sitemap2.xml), and I have tried adding an actual XML file instead of the dynamic one. Nothing works!

I have verified the XML file after I disabled the pre-renderer on multiple other sites and everyone gives me an "ok". It's as though it's ignoring my requests to re-check the file.

Sitemap location: https://www.tirex.se/sitemap.xml

**Edit 1:**
My current status as of 2021-09-02:
[image: Latest update]

Comment: How long has it been since you fixed the problem?   You said you tried waiting, but you didn't say how long.  It usually takes Google a couple weeks to update.   Have you tried inspecting the sitemap URL and doing a "live test?"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: I have been waiting since the 23:e of august, so a week.
It could take multiple weeks? :O
Yes, I tried inspecing the sitemap manually, in every way I could think of. Including visiting with different browser and using googlebot as user-agent.
Also requesting other sites that I found to validate the XML.

Comment: Google usually takes two weeks to update pretty much anything.  I wouldn't be surprised if it took 4 to 6 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the sitemap you posted with the network tab open in dev tools and I'm getting a 304 in the request headers.

*Edit: I did clear cache and refresh while I was answering and was still seeing 304. I just checked again and can confirm that I am no longer. Can't explain that unless something changed.*

If for some reason Google got a 304 at some point they'd be redirected to a previously (locally) cached result, which in your case could *ostensibly* be the old pre-rendered version (html).

Make sure that `https://example.com/sitemap.xml` returns 200 and to be safe double check your validation/fixes.

You also mentioned that you tried renaming the file - to further troubleshoot I would block the old version via robots.txt and also in that file list your sitemap.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
/sitemap2.xml

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Stephen *is* right about the time it takes to update, typically does take a couple weeks.

Edit2: Considering that you're using etags, I would recommend using an RSS/Atom feed in addition to your XML sitemap. RSS/Atom feeds might be more reliable, and will provide all updates on your site and keep your content fresher in Google's index.

Comment: If you clear your cache, you shouldn't get a 304.   Their server uses etags, so it should give a 304 if you have a copy, you refresh, and it hasn't changed.  Seems to work fine with curl:  `$ curl --head https://www.tirex.se/sitemap.xml`: `HTTP/2 200`

Comment: I tried clearing caches and refreshing while I was answering and was still getting 304. Checked with Chrome and Brave. Just tried curling and confirm 200 and re-checked same processes as before and now getting all 200 without clearing/refreshing.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Could it be possible that `If-None-Match` failed for some reason? That would cause the server must return HTTP status code 304, no? IDK I'm not confident/comfortable with it.

Comment: Would it be wise to turn of etags for the sitemap request? It could very likely be that the server is returning 304 to google considering that we havn't made any changes to the sitemap since first upload. (That I'm aware of, it's dynamicly generated, so maybe...)
@MikeCiffone: How would RSS/Atom benefit this situation? Why might it be more reliable? And what should be in it? Updates to the sitemap? Sorry I don't get it :P

Comment: @Wirde In general many recommend submitting both rss/atom + sitemap: one for recent changes and the other for your full "sitemap". In this case, if you include all of your pages, it would be a different form of sitemap (that Google for sure wouldn't have cached unless you already had it) that you could submit in Search Console to get what you care about done quicker (your content indexed?). If you want to keep bandwidth down, be specific about what bots you allow (but for sure googlebot).

Comment: @MikeCiffone: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind but, until we get the actuall sitemap to work i'm going to wait with introducing more complexity to this equation.
Something so simple as provideing a sitemap shoulden't be sush a hassle. The UX of interacting with google really sucks :(

Comment: @Wirde yeah. So how can I help you get to an accepted answer?

Comment: @MikeCiffone: Am I understanding you and Stephen correctly that you wan't me to wait a week or 2 more to see if anything changes?
If so, I'll have to wait and see if that actually solved the problem.
If it does I will accept your answer.
If you have anything you want me to try before that, that I have missed I'll try it ofcourse :)

Comment: I have added an image of my current state on the original post.

Comment: @Wirde can you also please remove e-tags on sitemaps just in case? Also if possible pull statuses from https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sitemaps ?

Comment: @MikeCiffone:
I have removed the etags from the entire server now, just to debug like you suggested. I tried pulling the information using the Sitemaps: get request.
This was the response: {
  "path": "https://www.tirex.se/sitemap.xml",
  "lastSubmitted": "2021-08-30T11:50:42.585Z",
  "isPending": true,
  "isSitemapsIndex": false,
  "lastDownloaded": "2021-08-23T20:18:23.429Z",
  "warnings": "0",
  "errors": "1"
}

Comment: I tired resubmitting it aswell, nothing changed so far. This is so wierd, really feels like google decided not to ever try again on this site...
I guess it's back to the waiting game again if you don't have anything more I could try? :)

Comment: @Wirde Sit tight...I'm pretty sure Google is preemptively testing for a broad core algorithm update right now (expected sometime before December 31). Even on my end across _all_ of my sites I'm seeing a lot of odd behavior in search console including false positive errors/warnings.